# What is Acle (Tesseract) doing when sticking out his thumb?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

See for example [this video](https://youtu.be/MpBIlDrvWKI?t=175). The song is Singularity, the time between 4:50 and 5:20. The musician appears to be using the [slapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapping_(music)) technique, but I am not sure. It also sounds unusually.

I am interested in an explanation as to what techinques are being used in this section of the song and to what end. One possibility is that this is indeed slapping, and it is used to make the attack sound differently than it would be with picking. But I do not know how to either confirm or refute this theory.

In other words, I want to understand the connexion between what fingers are doing and what sound comes out.

Comment: warning: ads in video

Comment: I've not watched with audio so can't tell what it sounds like, but it looks like he's either playing slap guitar or playing a tapped harmonic with his thumb.

Comment: Just watched with audio, he's playing slap guitar in this section.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley How do you hear it?

Comment: It's the attack you hear when he slaps the guitar. It doesn't sound like he's plucking or strumming the string, it definitely sounds like a slapping sound to me. Listen to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLNOgcEfBE4) - it's the same technique (albeit in a different tuning/genre).

Comment: @JamesWhiteley If you take these comments and make an answer out of them, I will be sure to accept it.